# Ubuntu 14.04 | Reset password asking me to Retype new password twice. Ideally it should be once

Tags: password, pam, reset, policy

I recently tried to implement password policy (at least one digit, upper case, lowercase, a special character) using pam_cracklib module. After that, the system asks me to retype password twice whenever I try to reset the password. Not sure if I modified the configuration file correctly. Did I made any mistake in the configuration file "common-password". Someone, please help me out.

1. Logged in as user

   ```
   $ passwd
   Changing password for testuser.
   (current) UNIX password:
   Enter new UNIX password:
   Retype new UNIX password:
   Retype new password:
   passwd: password updated successfully
   ```
2. Logged in as user

   ```
   $ passwd testuser
   Enter new UNIX password:
   Retype new UNIX password:
   Retype new password:
   passwd: password updated successfully
   ```
3. Logged in as Root

   ```
   $ sudo passwd testuser
   Enter new UNIX password:
   Retype new UNIX password:
   Retype new password:
   passwd: password updated successfully
   ```

My Configuration file content for ready reference.

```
$ grep "^[^#;]" /etc/pam.d/common-password 
password        [success=1 default=ignore]      pam_unix.so obscure  sha512 minlen=8 remember=7 shadow 
password        requisite                       pam_deny.so
password        required                        pam_permit.so 
password        requisite                       pam_cracklib.so    try_first_pass retry=3 use_authtok lcredit=-1 ucredit=-1 dcredit=-1 ocredit=-1
```

Comment: Use `sudo passwd testuser` and you won't be asked to retype at all.

Comment: I've been through this before. In my case, SO always asked twice for a password. I have to change 'try_first_pass' to 'use_first_pass'

Comment: @Redbob - I tried 'use_first_pass' but still no luck.

Comment: @Ziazis - The testuser is not a sudo user so as to use sudo command in front.

Comment: Look this. They talk about 3-times password: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1007323

Comment: You don't need to run passwd with the user you are actually on right now. That's why you can run `sudo passwd` to change the root password or you could run `sudo testuser passwd` to run passwd as testuser and have the same thing again. But if you don't want to have to confirm your password you'd need to run `sudo passwd testuser` so you forcefully change the password and since you're root everyone can assume you know what you're doing. Without being root you are a normal user and the average normal user is not smart. I wouldn't want to be bothered with misstyped passwords and needing a reset.

Comment: Also you need to type 3 times the new password because your usage of passwd is a little strange, if you are on the user you want to change the password you only need to type `passwd` then you would get asked for your current password and then the new one + retyping the new one. So not exactly sure what you did to get 3 times new password without needing your current one.

Comment: @Ziazis - Thanks for your quick reply. I did two things as informed by you. I switched to root and tried the command "sudo passwd testuser'. Then I switched to testuser and used commnd 'passwd'. Both the ways its asking me to retype password twice.

Comment: I have modified my question to avoid confusions as told by @Ziaziz.

Comment: Comment the last line in your common-password file, that's not there by default. [That's](https://linux.die.net/man/8/pam_cracklib) what probably causes you having an extra check of the new password, first is to check if it is "good enough" the other 2 are the normal type in password + check if you did a mistake.

Comment: @Ziazis - No I can't. I use the last line in common-password to enforce strong password policy. Ans its already mentioned in my original question.

Comment: Should rephrase the question to how you configure that module, without an extra password request. Because your question right now is why you have an extra password question. Answer is your module is at fault here at the moment.

Comment: @Ziazis - I rephrased my question. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

change this line:

```
password        [success=1 default=ignore]      pam_unix.so obscure  sha512 minlen=8 remember=7 shadow
```

to:

```
password        [success=1 default=ignore]      pam_unix.so obscure use_authtok sha512 minlen=8 remember=7 shadow
```

I added use_authtok

When password changing enforce the module to set the new password to the one provided by a previously stacked password module.